# Navier-Stokes equations in tensorial form on a general coordinate system

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, fluid-dynamics

How to write the classical Navier-Stokes equations in tensorial form on a general coordinate system? Any references?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the best I have come up with.  First, the Euler equation:
Let $L_uv = u\cdot \nabla v - v\cdot\nabla u$ denote the Lie derivative.  On the space of divergence free vector fields, the formal adjoint of this operator is
$$ L_u^* v = -u\cdot\nabla v - v \cdot (\nabla u)^T - \nabla q $$
where $q$ is a scalar field so that $L_u^* v$ is divergence free via the Hodge decomposition.  In the particular case $u=v$ you get
$$ L_u^* u = -u\cdot\nabla u - \nabla (q + \tfrac12 |u|^2) $$
and so pressure is $q + \frac12 |u|^2$.  (Note $q$ is not the head pressure from Bernoulli's formula - the signs are wrong.)  Also remember that the formula for $L_u^* u$ is treating $u$ both as a vector field in the subscript, and as a 1-form (i.e. covariant vector).  (I  Also remember that the formula for $L_u^* u$ is treating $u$ both as a vector field in the subscript, and as a 1-form (i.e. covariant vector).  I have seen the notation $u^\flat$ in this context, which I think converts $u$ from a vector to a 1-form.

The viscosity term is rather difficult.  This is because the Laplacian is not of a scalar, and so the usual formulas for Laplacian in other coordinate systems don't apply.

Anyway, $\Delta u = - d^* d u$, where $d$ is the exterior derivative of 1-forms, and $d^*$ is the adjoint operator on rank 2 contravarient tensors.  Normally the Beltrami-Laplacian operator is $-\Delta = d d^* + d^* d$, but since $u$ is divergence free $d d^* u = 0$.  In three dimensions $\Delta u = - \text{curl}(\text{curl} u)$.

I tried really hard to write the Navier-Stokes equation in spherical coordinates using this approach.  But in the end I found it easier just to write everything in Mathematica, and have it grind through the formulas.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer, I shall come back to this. I wasn't able to find stuff like this in books. I will have to figure out how to do this in Mathematica.

Comment: One more thing - I am finding this math.stackexchange quite addictive.  So I plan to try quitting son.  If you have other questions about NS, you might want to email me telling me you have posted a question.